# Can I use this MOSFET based on these parameters?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, pcb, circuit-design, mosfet-driver

**Motor specifications:**

- Maximum current: 15 A
- Ipulse: 30 A

I am using MOSFET as a switch to drive between 36V (42V maximum and 30V minimum) battery and a motor (15A Maxinum.)

I am not using PWM as a gate voltage to drive it. I am using constant DC 3.3V from my microcontroller and I am amplifying it using an NPN transistor to get 10V as my gate voltage to drive the MOSFET with low Rdson.

Please find the below circuit.

[image]

The above circuit explains that when the base voltage is 0 I will get 10V from collector to drive my MOSFET ON. When I give 3.3V as a base voltage my MOSFET will be off. Based on this I am switching the rail between battery and motor.

I am using IPD088N06N3 MOSFET for switching.

Can I use this MOSFET for my application? It has very low  Rdson.

[image]

**Conduction Loss:**

I^2 * Rdson = (15A)^2 * 8.8 mohm = 1.98 W

**Total Power Loss:**

((max Tj) - (Ta))/ Rthja = (175-25)/62 = 2.4 W

If I see based on the power loss I can use this MOSFET because 1.98 W is less than 2.4 W.

When it comes to switching losses I am confused because I am not using PWM to control the switches the MOSFET will turn off the rail when the charge or discharge current exceeds the threshold values. Until that the MOSFET will be on. How can I calculate switching losses?

Can I use this MOSFET for my application based on losses?

Eon= (15)(42)(45ns)/2 = 28.35 uJ

[image]

Can I use this MOSFET based on my application and I will use it for bidirectional purpose based on that so can I use this MOSFET. Please find the [datasheet here.](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/399737/INFINEON/IPD088N06N3G.html)

Comment: Your schematic doesn't show a motor. Neither does it show how the MOSFET source might be referenced to signal ground. Please fix. Could you also explain what \$Ipulse\$ is?

Comment: Mosfet is connected between battery and motor negative Rail .There is no ground positive of the battery is connected to positive of the motor or charger and negative of the battery is connected to the negative of motor or charger. when the charge or discharge value reaches the threshold value the microcontroller will detect using current sensing amplifier and Mosfets will be turned off. can i use this mosfet Sir. ignore Ipulse sir it the maximum pulse current for a sec passes through the rail .

Comment: No, that makes no sense - update your picture and avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: I have updated the pic sir . and the Mofets work in this way as it mentioned in this article when it is used in BMS for charge and discharge control https://patents.justia.com/patent/5883495

Comment: You cannot have a floating source (V3) and motor connected like that. The MOSFET needs to have a signal ground reference.

Comment: You will most likely need a freewheeling diode across the motor and a (small) heatsink for your MOSFET. What’s the stall current of your motor? Can your MOSFET survival that startup current without any soft start?